# How to install Jenkins on WebSphere 8.5

Tags: jenkins, websphere-8

I'm trying to install jenkins(1.627) as it is described on the [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+WebSphere), although I got this error.

Failed to load webapp: SRVE8111E: The application, jenkins_war, is trying to modify a cookie which matches a pattern in the restricted programmatic session cookies list [domain=*, name=JSESSIONID, path=/]

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact i just change the cookie name:

```
Websphere Application Servers -> session management -> enable cookies
-> Cookie Name
```

Changed it to another name(I set to JSESSIONID_jenkins), and it worked.

Comment: Yes, that should work also, as the cookie name is no longer on that programmatic cookie list then :-)

Comment: I am also trying to install latest jenkins (2.135) version on WAS 8.5.5.13.I am getting the same error as mentioned above.Tried the accepted answer but it didn't work.Is there anything else that I can do.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Somehow Jenkins app is trying to modify JSESSIONID cookie settings. Try to remove in the `Security > Global Security > Programmatic session cookie configuration` the matching row (`[domain=*, name=JSESSIONID, path=/]`). I didn't test that, so might not work.