# Jenkins fails when starting in WebSphere: NullPointerException in WebApp.getInitParameter()

Tags: jenkins, websphere, redhat

I have WebSphere 8.5.5.9 and want to run Jenkins on it, because of that, I have installed jenkins.war (the last version 2.19.2), but when I try to start it, I  get the error bellow and the application(Jenkins)  doesn't start.

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago) - 64 bits

```
[11/14/16 14:34:55:824 EST] 0000007c BootFailure   E   Failed to initialize Jenkins
                                 hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:248)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getInitParameter(WebApp.java:2791)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade.getInitParameter(ServletContextFacade.java:264)
    at jenkins.util.SystemProperties.tryGetValueFromContext(SystemProperties.java:322)
    at jenkins.util.SystemProperties.getString(SystemProperties.java:121)
    at jenkins.util.SystemProperties.getInteger(SystemProperties.java:258)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:599)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:231)
```

Does somebody have any idea what could be the rouse cause?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Jenkins on WebSphere 8.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374501/how-to-install-jenkins-on-websphere-8-5)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into other log from WebSphere I found an erro like this:

> restricted programmatic session cookie

looking new solutions to this new error, I found a solution:

Just remove on item from programmatic session cookie configuration

Cookie Domain:*
Cookie Name: "JSESSIONID" 
Cookie Path: /

from:

**Security > Global security > Programmatic session cookie configuration.**

After that, I could start Jenkins with success.